# remove .html with htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess

I'm using my htaccess file to try to remove .html (and other if I need to) file extensions from my web URL's.

The problem is it doesn't seem to work unless I go through my links in the site and manually remove .html from all of them (which makes testing the site locally quite annoying and I'm not sure if I'm supposed to remove the .html file extension).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

This works if a user types in www.mysite.com/about instead of www.mysite.com/about.html, except when clicking through the links of my site it still adds the extension?

What's the best way to go about removing the .html, absolute links on my site with http://www.mysite.com/about etc or should I remove the extension and just have paths like ../about instead of ../about.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.htaccess file does not change your code so if you put the extension in your page (for links), you must remove it.

Comment: Is removing the extension best practice for not having it in links or is there another way?

Comment: It's best practice because its not automatic with a htaccess file. URL Rewriting is a synonym, so if you write the extension, it's works => remove in your code and the synonym will be use.

Comment: So what you're saying is that there's no downside to removing the .html or .php extension in my code?

Comment: When you make a link, do not put the extension and get the desired effect since your URL rewriting seems to work well.

Comment: So is there even a way to remove the .html with htaccess and leave it in the code?

Comment: No because it's just a synonym in the htaccess